# How to reduce the execution time of rolling window apply function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Rolling mean using pandas rolling function taking too much time to execute. Input data is having 200 IDs with 30,00,000 rows taking around 5 minutes to run. Is there any way to reduce the execution time.

```
def group_rolling_window2(x):
    x['fuel_level_mean']=x[x['flag_outlier']==0]['fuel_level'].rolling('120s',closed='both',min_periods=5).mean()
    return x
 
df=df.set_index('timestamp').groupby('id').apply(group_rolling_window2).reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi Sangeetha R, this is a question better suited to Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/